# How do you normalize a table with a multi-valued field?

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-normalization

I want to normalize a staging table into two tables. One of the fields of input data contains multiple values delimited by a semicolon.

```
DATETIME | FILENAME | MULTIVALUEDFIELD
7-22-18 | somefile.txt | value1;value2;value3
```

I'm sure you data-wizards know where this is going, but I want this normalized thusly:

```
ID | FILENAME |
1 | somefile.txt
```

and

```
ID | SINGLEVALUES | OTHERTABLEID
1 | value1 | 1
2 | value2 | 1
3 | value3 | 1
```

Sorry for formatting issues: I didn't see a way to do tables. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Is it 1:M or M:N relationship? If 1:M then it's correct

Comment: You mean like one-to-many? the individual records are 1:M but those values can be repeated in other records, so the way I've got mapped out above would still cause value1, for example, to be listed in that normalized table multiple times.

Comment: Is there any significance to the order of values in `MULTIVALUEDFIELD`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you actually have a many-to-many relationship here; a `filename` can refer to many `singlevalues`, and `singlevalues` can appear in many `filename`s.

The traditional way to represent that would be with a bridge table that consists of foreign key references to the primary keys of `filename` and `singlevalues`, and, if it's applicable to your design, any additional fields that represent the relationship.

```
dbo.filename
+-------------+---------------+
| filename_sk |   filename    |
+-------------+---------------+
|           1 | somefile.txt  |
|           2 | otherfile.txt |
+-------------+---------------+
dbo.value
+----------+--------+
| value_sk | value  |
+----------+--------+
|        1 | value1 |
|        2 | value2 |
|        3 | value3 |
+----------+--------+
dbo.bridge
+-------------+----------+
| filename_sk | value_sk |
+-------------+----------+
|           1 |        1 |
|           1 |        2 |
|           2 |        2 |
|           2 |        3 |
+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: You, sir, are both intelligent, and breathtakingly attractive. Many thanks!

Comment: Who am I to argue? :) Glad it helped.